# Como trabalho com classes em python dentro de um serviço com Flask?

Tags: python, api, aplicação-web, web-service, flask

Estou tentando construir um serviço web com Flask e estou usando a biblioteca FlaskView.
Em meus testes construí o seguinte código:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_classful import FlaskView

app = Flask(__name__)

class HelloWorldView(FlaskView):
    route_base = '/'

    def index(self):
        return 'Hello, World!'

HelloWorldView.register(app)
```

Porém não funciona e me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\vinio\OneDrive - Extrabom Supermercados\Projetos\API Pipefy - SLA\teste.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_classful import FlaskView
  File "C:\Users\vinio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_classful.py", line 15, in <module>
    from werkzeug.routing import parse_rule
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_rule' from 'werkzeug.routing'
```

Já atualizei todas as bibliotecas e não funcionou.
Preciso de ajuda para montar o serviço de forma profissional e queria usar classes por isso. Aceito novas ideias e métodos mais válidos.
Desde já, agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score -2):

Tens que fazer downgrade do Flask e do Werkzeug para a versão 2.1.2

```
pip install Flask==2.1.2
pip install Werkzeug==2.1.2
```

E para correr a aplicação falta este código:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```